# Encryption and Decryption in Hibernate 3.0 without using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption, hibernate-mapping

I'm using **IBM DB2 9.7** and **hibernate 3.0**. I've an encrypted column in one of my tables. How can I map that column in **.hbm** file to read and write data.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is encrypted you need to know the algorithm how it was encrypted in order to decrypt it, sometimes it is impossible to decrypt if some *hash* function was used.
Could you please provide more details.

Comment: Algorithm used is RC4. To insert data using IDE I'm using **INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName) VALUES(ENCRYPT('47138'));** and for fetching **SELECT DECRYPT_CHAR(ColumnName) FROM TableName;**.

Comment: Now the question is how can I achieve this using HQL?